# Meaning of x_descenders and x_ascenders in hOCR file?

Tags: tesseract, hocr

Here's the line from Tesseract 4 output (.hocr file):

```
<span class='ocr_line' 
      id='line_1_1' 
      title="bbox 36 92 580 122; baseline 0 -6; x_size 30; x_descenders 6; x_ascenders 6">
```

What's the meaning of `x_descenders` and `x_ascenders` properties?

I know in typography a [descender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) is "the portion of a letter that extends below the baseline of a font". But there are situations when x_descenders is not an *integer* but a *float* like in `x_descenders 5.2608695`. Then what that would mean?

Then I wonder how to interpret decimal parts of

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I thought ```x_ascenders``` is the integer variable ```asscount``` from the forloop. It appears to be the float variable ```ascenders```.

Comment: @GradaGukovic No problem. I will need to dig through https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/search?p=2&q=descenders&unscoped_q=descenders. Still I wonder how this information is used later to understand and extract information from .hocr files. I guess it's not.

Comment: Hello, did you find any useful information or if they are of any use?